# Update previously undefined variable for asynchronous callback function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

Let's have a look at this short JavaScript snippet:

```js
function _function(param1, param2) {
  console.log(param1 + " and " + param2);
}

function test(callback) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = undefined;
  var test = setTimeout(callback.bind(null, i, j), 1000);
  i = 1;
  j = 2;
}

test(_function);
```

Now it works as expected: `console.log` is going to display

> 0 and **undefined**

Is it possible to **only** *update* `j` (here: to 2) while keeping `i` equal to `0` within `_functions`'s scope  and without using `j` as a global variable ?

Comment: function calls are pass-by-value, not pass by reference.

Comment: Alter your `test` function to take `j` as an argument, then you could just call `test(_function, 2)`. It's not clear why you would want it to work the way you're asking.